# Vray-like displacement

Tags: displacement

I've recently started using Blender in favour of 3ds max with Vray. 3ds max allowed me to use a detailed displacement map on a simple plane which resulted in 3D displacement. It was very effetive to create intricaty with minimal amount of modelling and keeping the files light. Blender seems not to be able to do this. In order to displace the mesh needs to be heavily subdivided to produce pleasing results. Is this correct, or am I missing something? Is there plans to implement this in Blender?

Ludvig

Comment: I am awere of the bump function, which works well when looking straight at planes, but is flawed when seeing at an angle (like floors often are)

Comment: 3ds Max displacement also creates additional geometry. There is no way to do true displacement without additional geometry. From the 3ds Max KB: "Warning: A Displacement map can generate many triangular faces per surface, sometimes over one million faces per surface. While using a Displacement map can produce impressive results, it can cost a lot in terms of computation time and memory."

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That makes sense, however when it happens under the hood like that, it makes for efficient workflows where simple planes may be edited. Would you suggest simply adding subv surface with simple checked to achieve the same?

Comment: Yeah - you either have to use a sub-d modifier or manually subdivide your mesh to get detailed displacement. Since you have to turn on experimental features anyway, you might as well use the adaptive subsurf option. This can lower the total amount of tris created during tessellation.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

Blender/Cycles has render-time displacement in the (still in 2.81) Experimental feature set.

It can be combined with [Adaptive Subdivision](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/adaptive_subdiv.html#adaptive-subdivision)

This plane is subdivided only once in the working geometry:

[image]

The rest is done at render-time:

[image]

(In its Properties tab > Surface panel, the material's Displacement settings include 'Displacement')